# Magento 2 : Adding a foreign key of customer_entity in a custom table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to add a foreign key of the customer in my table in InstallSchema file :

```
$installer->getConnection()
                ->addColumn($installer->getTable('fmj_crf/projet'), 'customer_fk_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                        ), 'customer Id');

        $installer->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
                $installer->getFkName('fmj_crf/projet', 'customer_fk_id', 'customer_entity', 'entity_id'), $installer->getTable('fmj_crf/projet'), 'customer_fk_id', $installer->getTable('customer_entity'), 'entity_id'
        );
```

but when I upgrade it gives me this error :

```
[PDOException]                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'fmj_crf/projet'.   
  Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'test2/FMJ_CRF/PROJET_CUSTOMER_FK_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_I  
  D'
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: whats your custom table name?

Comment: the name is fmj_crf/projet

Comment: Are you using upgrade schema or Install Schema. In your question you have mentioned use of InstallSchema and In below you have written when upgrade gives you error. Clarify it.

Comment: I'm using InstallSchema , and after I run the command setup:upgrade to enable my module I had the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by changing the definition to the foreign key column in the upgradeSchema file like this :

```
$setup->getConnection()->changeColumn(
                    'fmj_crf/projet', 'customer_fk_id', 'customer_fk_id', ['type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true,]
            );
```

and then :

```
$setup->getConnection()->addForeignKey(
                    $setup->getFkName(
                            'fmj_crf/projet', 'customer_fk_id', 'customer_entity', 'entity_id'
                    ), $setup->getTable('fmj_crf/projet'), 'customer_fk_id', $setup->getTable('customer_entity'), 'entity_id', \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $setup->getConnection()
            ->addForeignKey(
                $setup->getFkName(
                    'your_custom_table_name',                   // priTableName
                    'your_custom_table_field',                  // priColumnName
                    'customer_entity',                          // refTableName
                    'entity_id'                                 // refColumnName
                ),
                'your_custom_table_field',                      // column
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity'), 
                'entity_id',                                    // refColumn
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE // onDelete
```